How to update UI in Jetpack Compose from ViewModel UIState based on two values?
I'm a little confused with the following scenario:

Initially I am displaying a DatePicker modal on the screen.

When the user selects a date, I display several buttons.

And when the user clicks on any of those buttons, I want to pass to the ViewModel the two pieces of data: the selected date and the type of button that was pressed, to search for data in the repository with those two criteria.


My problem is that I can't find a way to pass the two pieces of data, before the ViewModel is included.
I'm trying to do something like InterestsScreen in Now In Android.
I have a similar code in another scenario where it works, but there the date is taken from the system, so there is no problem. Here the date must be given by the user, from a DatePicker.
I don't show the code for the UseCase or the Repository, that code works fine when I pass it the correct parameters. My problem is that I don't know how to make the call to the ViewModel when I have the selected date and the type of button that the user has pressed.
I show the relevant parts of my code:
NavGraphBuilder
composable<CalendarRoute> {
    CalendarScreen(onTopicClick = onTopicClick,onDateSelected={})


CalendarScreen (called from NavGraphBuilder)
@Composable
fun CalendarScreen(
    onTopicClick: (String) -> Unit,
    onDateSelected: (Long?) -> Unit,
    viewModel: CalendarViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    DatePickerAndButtons(
        onTopicClick = viewModel::onTopicClick,
        onDateSelected = viewModel::onDateSelected,
        uiState = uiState
    )
}


DatePickerAndButtons
@ExperimentalLayoutApi
@Composable
fun DatePickerAndButtons(
    onTopicClick: (String) -> Unit,
    onDateSelected: (Long?) -> Unit,
    uiState: CalendarUiState
) {
    var showTopics by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var showDatePicker by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    var selectedDate by remember { mutableStateOf<Long?>(null) }

    when (uiState) {
        CalendarUiState.Empty -> Text("Empty")
        CalendarUiState.Error -> Text("Error")
        CalendarUiState.Loading -> {
            Text("Loading")
            //showDatePicker=true
        }
        is CalendarUiState.CalendarData -> {
            showTopics=false
            //showDatePicker=false
            if(uiState.topics.isNotEmpty()) {
                //Show data
            }else{
                //¿?
            }
        }
    }

    if (selectedDate != null) {
        val date = Date(selectedDate!!)
        val formattedDate = SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(date)
        Text("Selected date: $formattedDate")
    } else {
        Text("No date selected")
    }
    if (showDatePicker) {
        DatePickerModal(
            onDateSelected = {
                selectedDate = it
                onDateSelected(it)
                //viewModel.onDateSelected(selectedDate)
                showDatePicker = false
                showTopics=true
            },
            onDismiss = { showDatePicker = false }
        )
    }

    if(showTopics) {
        //Code that create buttons to be clicked
    }

}

ViewModel
@HiltViewModel
class CalendarViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    val userDataRepository: UserDataRepository,
    val universalisRepository: UniversalisRepository,
    getTopicWithDate: GetUniversalisFromCalendarUseCase,
) : ViewModel() {
    private val selectedTopicIdKey = "selectedTopicIdKey"
    private val selectedDateKey = "selectedDateKey"
    private val calendarRoute: CalendarRoute = savedStateHandle.toRoute()
    private val selectedTopicId = savedStateHandle.getStateFlow(
        key = selectedTopicIdKey,
        initialValue = "1" //calendarRoute.topicId,
    )
    private val selectedDate = savedStateHandle.getStateFlow(
        key = selectedDateKey,
        initialValue = 0
    )
    
    val uiState: StateFlow<CalendarUiState> = combine(
        selectedTopicId,
        getTopicWithDate.invoke(
            date = selectedDate.value,
            title = "TODO:Title",
            selectedTopicId = selectedTopicId.value
        ),
        CalendarUiState::CalendarData,
    ).
    stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
        initialValue = CalendarUiState.Loading,
    )


    fun onTopicClick(topicId: String?) {
        savedStateHandle[selectedTopicIdKey] = topicId
    }

    fun onDateSelected(date: Long?) {
        savedStateHandle[selectedDateKey] = date
    }
    
}


The code you provided is hard to understand. Please remove everything that isn't needed (like the LazyColumn). But there are also some important parts missing, like how you call the repository. And finally, please point out the parts of your code that you have issues with. As it is now it is not clear what you are actually asking.

@Leviathan Thanks for your interest. I've edited the question. I hope it's clearer now. Basically my problem is that here the information that should be sent to the ViewModel is collected in two stages: 1. The date from the DatePicker; 2. The type of button that will be pressed once the date is obtained. In the ViewModel I should use those two pieces of data to query the repository. I didn't show the repository because this same code works in another scenario where the date is taken from the system. My problem is collecting those two data and sending them to the ViewModel.

You have incorrectly combined two different stages of flow.
The topicId and date are query parameters for the Topic, so the query only starts when they change.
So your topic query results will be like:
    private val topics: Flow<YourTopicsModel> = combine(
        selectedDate,
        selectedTopicId,
    ){date,topicId->
        date to topicId
    }.flatMapLatest {
        getTopicWithDate(
            date = it.first,  
            title = "TODO:Title",
            selectedTopicId = it.second
        )
    }

Then your uiState will be:
    val uiState: StateFlow<CalendarUiState> = combine(
        selectedTopicId,
        topics,
        CalendarUiState::CalendarData,
    ).
    stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
        initialValue = CalendarUiState.Loading,
    )


Ok. With your code I can collect selectedTopicId and selectedDate and pass the query with the two parameters to the UseCase and from there to the repository. But there is a problem: when the screen is opened for the first time topics: Flow<Universalis> = combine(...) is called, and at that moment the variables have no data. Is there a way to avoid that first call? The code works as expected by initially setting default values, but an unnecessary call is occurring with those default values.

I have found the solution to the problem raised in the previous comment: First show the composable with the DatePicker, without any reference to the ViewModel, and when the date is chosen, call another composable where I pass the date as a parameter and in that composable I create the reference to the ViewModel, I pass the date by calling onDateChange and I create the reference to CalendarUiState. Thanks for your answer.
